# Left Join of Two Data Table into one two DataTabale

Tags: vb.net

Here is my Scenario

I Have First Datable :TableA

```
     **Item**    **Place**  

      ItemA      PlaceA
      ItemB      PlaceB
      ItemE      PlaceE
```

I Have Second Datable :TableB

```
  **Item**            **Status**
-------------------------------
   ItemC             Complete

   ItemD             Complete

   ItemE             Complete
```

Output New DataTable Will Look Like This

```
   Item        Place       Status
----------------------------------------------

   ItemA     PlaceA

   ItemB     PlaceB

   ItemC                Complete

   ItemD                Complete

   ItemE     PlaceE     Complete
```

Please give me the Solution in VB.Net

Comment: In sql, this would be called a full join.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick example:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Serial", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Item", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Place", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Rows.Add(New String() {"001", "ItemA", "PlaceA"})
    dt.Rows.Add(New String() {"002", "ItemB", "PlaceB"})


    Dim dt1 As New DataTable()
    dt1.Columns.Add("Serial", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt1.Columns.Add("Item", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt1.Columns.Add("Status", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt1.Rows.Add(New String() {"003", "ItemC", "Complete"})
    dt1.Rows.Add(New String() {"003", "ItemD", "Complete"})

    dt.Merge(dt1)
```

The last line is the most important, which merges the contents of one datatable with the contents of another.

Should do the trick!!